# What is the time to live of a single message telemetry on Azure Notification Hub?

Tags: azure-notificationhub, ttl, telemetry

How long the telemetry of a single message will be retained on Azure Notification Hub? Should we get the telemetry and store offline if we want to trace a message 7 days later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telemetry is retained by the system for 30 days. Also worth noting that notification telemetry is only available when on the Standard SKU.

I see now that this value doesn't appear to be documented. I'll see if I can get the Notification Hubs documents updated to properly reflect this. Thank you for raising the question.